# Installation of mysqlclient fails on shared hosting server using pip

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

I want to connect the Django app to mysql database. The recommended solution is to install mysqlclient through pip. But the installation fails through the provided interface of the shared hosting service.

I tried to install over ssh, and the error log is quite bug and there was a error about permissions. There is no access to sudo commands in the shared hosting service.

Comment: alternatively you can use [pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) but it does not work with django>2.2

Comment: I'm using the version 2.2.1, so there is no way of using pymysql.

Comment: This might help with pymysql: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/790#issuecomment-489318466

Answer (score 0):

**Django Solution** using **PyMySQL** pure python implementation.

```
1. pip install PyMySQL or PyMySQL = "*" in Pipfile
2. Editing __init__.py in base or config directory where settings.py exits

   import pymysql
   pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 2, "final", 0)
   pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Please feel free to share if you need more specific use cases.